# Using an img. subdomain with cmsms to increase load-times

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system, subdomain

I am currently using CMS Made Simple 1.11.2. I have created a subdomain of img.domain.com and would like to use that for all images used on the site. With cmsms images are typically stored in domain.com/cms/uploads/images/*.*.

In other words any references to images in urls should be converted to use the new subdomain such as img.domain.com/cms/example.jpg.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. In your CMS and all the content generated by your CMS, change the links to look like `http://img.domain.com/image_filename.jpg`. If you don't do this, you'd still be using the old links.

Step2. Add these rules to the htaccess file of the `img.domain.com` document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cms/uploads/images%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /cms/uploads/images%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If the img subdomain and your main domain have different document roots, or are on different servers, you'll need to use mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/cms/uploads/images/$1 [L,P]
```